# H.264 over RTP: P-frame interpolation

Tags: h.264, rtp

In a H.264 stream just containing I-frames and P-frames I wonder if, in packet loss presence, would be possible to interpolate any lost P-frame in a "relatively easy way".

Imagine:    I P P P ... (original) --> I X P P ...  (received)

I P P P ...  --> I P X P...  and so on...

Looking at the H.264 diagram block it does not seem so easy...(e.g. [High-Profile block diagram](http://www.cast-inc.com/ip-cores/video/h264-hp-e/h264-hp-e-block-diagram.png)).

Currently, I am working with H.264 dynamic payload types 96 and 97; Baseline and High Video Profiles just for receiving video, in case it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the *entire* frame is lost, the short answer: no, there’s no “relatively easy way”. Even if you employ every H264 error concealment trick, you’ll end up with lost pixel data subsequent P frames refer to, and visually unpleasant results.

Now, it’s very rare to lose the entire frame. If the packet loss is so severe, the best way to recover would be to retransmit lost packets (if latency allows) or even ask the server for new I frame (I assume that you have robust network stack with feedback loop to the server).

To solve packet loss problems, is much better is to focus on resilience and data redundancy. I highly recommend presentation [Error resiliency and concealment](http://www.slideshare.net/coldfire7/error-resiliency-and-concealment-in-h264-presentation) in h264 and [another paper on the same subject](http://attila.sdsu.edu/~wmc/Papers/JVCI154_Kumar_final.pdf) - they describe many mitigation techniques like flexible macroblock/slice ordering and redundant slices. Unfortunately, I cannot provide links to the existing implementations - real time video streaming is a very narrow field, and all companies who run active research and development keep their implementations secret.

Comment: When you point to "entire frame"...are you referring to an entire P-frame? In my case, as I am developing the client application, which processes the RTP packets, I don't think I could take advantage from error resiliency techniques. They must be implemented in the server part...am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, all techniques require support in both client and server. So what kind of stream it is? Does it insert I frame at predefined intervals?

Comment: Yes, the stream comes with I frames at predefined intervals (e.g. 15 @ 12 FPS, 30 @ 25 FPS, ando so on...)

Comment: Tough call. I think the simplest solution is to pause the stream until next I frame arrives. Also take a look at the error concealment algorithm on page 15 in the second document in the answer - is it feasible to implement in your client?